# Junit parallel execution of same task

Tags: java, junit, completable-future

I found a bug in code, and I know that when 20 threads are running the code in parallel something fails. Now I'd like to create test for it, but I don't know how to write it.

```
@Test
public void testAuthPerformance() {
    int numberOfCalls = 20;
    CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<OAuth2AccessToken>>[] tasksArray = new CompletableFuture[numberOfCalls];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCalls; i++) {
        tasksArray[i] = CompletableFuture
                .supplyAsync(() -> new OauthCaller().callAuth(), executorService);
    }

    CompletableFuture.allOf(tasksArray).join();
    for (CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<OAuth2AccessToken>> task : tasksArray) {
        ResponseEntity<OAuth2AccessToken> responseEntity = task.join();
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, responseEntity.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

problem is that task.join seems like it's performing in sequence instead of parallel.

In logs I can see following which seems to me like sequential execution:

```
2017-03-27 13:00:13.263 DEBUG 37381 --- [nio-9999-exec-4] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /oauth/token
2017-03-27 13:00:13.263 DEBUG 37381 --- [nio-9999-exec-4] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException]
2017-03-27 13:00:13.264 DEBUG 37381 --- [nio-9999-exec-4] .o.p.p.ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter : Getting access token for: demo
2017-03-27 13:00:13.342 DEBUG 37381 --- [nio-9999-exec-6] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /oauth/token
2017-03-27 13:00:13.342 DEBUG 37381 --- [nio-9999-exec-6] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException]
2017-03-27 13:00:13.345 DEBUG 37381 --- [nio-9999-exec-6] .o.p.p.ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter : Getting access token for: demo
2017-03-27 13:00:13.482 DEBUG 37381 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /oauth/token
2017-03-27 13:00:13.482 DEBUG 37381 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException]
2017-03-27 13:00:13.483 DEBUG 37381 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] .o.p.p.ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter : Getting access token for: demo
```

With following code I can simulate the issue, but there's no simple way for assertions.

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        executorService.execute(() -> new OauthCaller().callAuth());
    }
} finally {
    executorService.shutdown();
}
```

can someone please suggest the way how to unit test such code? Thanks

Comment: Does it help to call `Collections.shuffle(taskArray)` before joining?

Comment: How do you know it is not random order?  `CompletableFuture.allOf(tasksArray).join();` waits for all tasks to complete, and then you check them in the order of creation.  It doesn't mean they completed in that order.

Comment: How does it fail if the test fails?  Deadlock?

Comment: ok sorry about that order. I don't care about order. I just wanted to say, that tasks seems to be executed sequentially instead of parallel. There's no deadlock, there wrong state which is comming from  `new OauthCaller().callAuth()`

Comment: For me it looks like your tasks execute faster than the time it takes to supply and start them. I suppose you actually mock the backend, maybe you could try adding some delay in that mock?